# How to call method of class passed as parameter

Tags: java

I'm trying to pass a subclass as a parameter and then create an instance of it, but I'm getting the error message on the line where I instantiate the transformation class (incompatible types).  If I try to instantiate using `transClass trans = new transClass()`, it complains that `transClass` is unknown.  Here's the code I'm using.

```
abstract class Transformation {
  abstract public Object transform(Object obj);
}
class MyTransformation extends Transformation {
  public Object transform(Object obj){
    // do stuff to obj
    return obj;
  }
}

class AnotherClass {
  public doSomething(Object obj, Class<Transformation> transClass){
    // do more stuff to obj
    Transformation trans = new transClass();  // fails with "Incompatible Types", referring to 'Transformation' and 'transClass'
    // transClass trans = new transClass(); // alternate attempt, also fails with "Unknown Type" on 'transClass'
    return trans.transform(obj);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the static method?

Comment: Sorry, removed 'static' from title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`Class#newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--):

```
public <T extends Transformation> Object doSomething(Object obj, Class<T> transClass)
    throws Exception {
    // do more stuff to obj
    Transformation trans = transClass.newInstance();
    return trans.transform(obj);
}
```

Comment: +1, your answer is good, but the parameter `transClass` probably should be of type `Class<? extends Transformation>`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It shows me `java.lang.InstantiationException` if I pass `Transformation.class` as class in `doSomething()` method. Can an abstract class be instantiated?

Comment: @Braj you will get it if you pass `Transformation` because it's an abstract class. You should pass a child of `Transformation` like `MyTransformation` as provided in OP's code.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza now your updated code is working fine.